# Flutter: Rendering image using GetX and ExternalPath results in PathNotFoundException

Tags: flutter, image, dart

so i have this function to get the file path from my phone, im using GetX

```dart
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement HomeController

  TextEditingController fileName = TextEditingController();
  File? image;
  List<String> exPath = [];
  String? path;

  Future GetFiles() async {
    try {
      final picPath = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
      path =
          "$picPath/Telegram/image1.jpeg"; // this is just the example of my directory
      print(path);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting external storage path: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }
}
  }
```

and i want to render the file

```dart
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(HomeController());
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: Wrap(
          runSpacing: 15,
          children: [
            Image.file(File(controller.path!)), // the image must be rendered here
            InputField(label: "File name  ", controller: controller.fileName),
            SizedBox(
                width: 1.sw,
                height: 50.h,
                child: ButtonActive("Search", onTap: () => controller.GetFiles()))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

but i have an issue

The following PathNotFoundException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Telegram/image1.jpeg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

what should i do?

so i expect the file from my phone is rendered in my widget.

Comment: Check into your file manager if the "image1.jpeg" is exist on '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Telegram/image1.jpeg' path or not?

Comment: yea, i have the file on that path

Answer (score 0):

When the Widget is build for the first time, the value of the path variable is null, so `Image.file(File(controller.path!))` will throw an exception. You are calling the function `GetFiles()`, in which the value is assigned to the path variable in `onTap()` method which won't be called initially unless you click the button.
You can either put a null check on the path variable or call the `GetFiles()` function in the initState method before the widget tree is built.